# ATI Radeon HD 4650 underclocks itself and crashes

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

My video card is underclocks its GPU, at idle it's 165 mhz, when recording screen it overclocks to 600 mhz (max 600 mhz). But when I play fullscreen games, sometimes screen flickers because GPU clock speed drops sometimes to 300 or 165 mhz. How to fix this?

Maybe my computer is too weak? My specs:

```
Hewlett-Packard HP d530 SFF motherboard
CPU Properties  
CPU Type - Intel Pentium 4, 2800 MHz (21 x 133)
CPU Alias - Northwood
CPU Stepping - D1
Package Type - 478 Pin uPGA
Instruction Set - x86, MMX, SSE, SSE2
Original Clock - 2800 MHz
Min / Max CPU Multiplier - 21x / 21x
Engineering Sample - No
L1 Trace Cache - 12K Instructions
L1 Data Cache - 8 KB
L2 Cache - 512 KB  (On-Die, ECC, ATC, Full-Speed)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it is overheating. Check the CPU core and memory temperatures.  The 4000 series were notorious for overheating.

I have two 4870s and I have six fans blowing at them to keep them to overclock.

Comment: My video card temp is about 38 - 47 C, it was my case overheating

Comment: Sorry but it isnt. I havent found any answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

The GPU should lower its clock only when it's underused. Did you try a benchmark or another game (more graphic-intensive)? Also, you can try to disable the power saving: [How to disable ATi Powerplay](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/619718-How-to-disable-ATi-Powerplay)

A workaround might be to limit the fps (if the game allows it).

Comment: The problem was in graphics drivers that I installed came in CD. After I downloaded the newest drivers from the site, everything worked alomost perfect. I moved to Windows 7 and now everything works PERFECT.

Comment: @Roberts: you could add that to the question, so it would be easier to spot.